# How to allow only 4 cells per row in a table in HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml, html4

I'd like to know if there's a way to allow only 4 cells per row in HTML .. only 4   allowed in a table , if it's more than 4 tds , then another row  gets created ..

How could I control that in HTML ?

Comment: How are you generating table?

Comment: through PHP , there are many elements in the database and I only want 4 cells per row in the table .. I'd to know how to do that in HTML ... there must be a way

Comment: Your question is a little unclear (I assume). If you're using html, then simply dont add more than 4 tds per tr. If you're using javascript, see 2nd sentence. If you're using php, aspx, jsp - again, see the second sentence,

Comment: I mean show us some codes you have tested so far...

Comment: You dont seem to understand my question at all ... maybe someone else will ... I would like to control the table rows .. only 4 cells .. its that simple to understand ... I want to do that with only HTML

Comment: if you want to do using html then give 4 td in tr otherwise if you do using php then give condition.

Comment: Use the iteration property of foreach loop

Comment: The question is not clear?? It seems very clear to me. I'll post it now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't seem to understand what you're asking.
You CANNOT do this automatically with *only* html. Your question pertains to both Html and Php.

Here's a quick n nasty job:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbName", $userName, $pwd);

$query = $pdo->prepare('select name from products order by id asc');
$query->execute();

echo '<table>';
echo '<tbody>';
$numCellsInRow = 0;
while ($curRow = $query->fetch())
{
    if ($numCellsInRow == 4)
    {
        printf("</tr>");
        $numCellsInRow = 0;
    }
    if ($numCellsInRow == 0)
    {
        printf("<tr>");
    }
    printf("<td>%s</td>", $curRow[0]);

    $numCellsInRow++;
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

**Result**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1" tweeter</td>
      <td>6" sub</td>
      <td>Sony Headphones</td>
      <td>Magnifier</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Red Led</td>
      <td>Blue LED</td>
      <td>7 segment LED</td>
      <td>Lalique stained glass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>LED downlight</td>
      <td>BiPole light-switch</td>
      <td>DC, 10amp</td>
      <td>Monster Cable</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sata 2.0 Cable</td>
      <td>Speaker Wire</td>
      <td>USB 2.0 A to B Cable</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you dont seem to understand WHAT I WAS ASKING . I was wondering if HTML can allow to do this , which is why I ASKED !

Comment: **Please re-read the second sentence of my solution.** HTML is a markup language - it does not have the ability to make decisions. You need to make decisions when determining whether to add a new cell to the current row or if you need to add it to a new row. I am certain I understand your question - I'm not so sure of your intended emphasis by way of the selective capitalization you used. Anyway, I'm glad the solution is useful to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. havn't tested..

```
 $count = 0; 
    echo("<table><tr>");
    foreach ($products as $product) { 
    if(($count % 4) == 0){

    echo("</tr><tr>\n");
    $count++;

    }if
    else{
    $count++;
    }

    echo("<td>$product<td>");

    }


    echo("</tr></table>");
```